# ActiveRecord Query Where Last has_many Record Matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a class, let's Contact with many Transitions ...

```
class Contact
    has_many :transitions
    ...
end

class Transition
    belongs_to contact
    ...
end
```

What I'd like to do is find all of the contacts whose *last* transition was performed by the 'system'. Obviously, the Transition has a `performed_by` column that can be either 'system' or 'user'. I'm trying a few different things, but can't get what I really need. I'm thinking something along the lines of ...

```
Contact.
joins(:transitions).
where('transitions.performed_by = ', 'system')
```

but this will get all contacts that have *any* transition with 'system' and I only want the ones where the last transition was by 'system'.

Thoughts?

Comment: i am not sure do you really need like this `Transition.where(:performed_by => 'system').order("created_at ASC").last.contact`

Comment: I actually simplified the real problem a bit and this will be in the middle of some other Contact queries (scope/stubby lambda). I'll take a look though and see if I can go in this direction @Kingston. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this

```
contact = Contacts.first
contact.transitions.where(:performed_by => 'system').last
```